# Cannot open shapefile in R

Tags: r, rgdal

I am not sure why but I cant read shapefiles at all in r!

On a MacOS Mojave,

I have tried:

```
afg <- readOGR("afg.shp")
afg <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "afg")
```

The shapefiles are from this website: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata, Afghanistan roads.

This same error keeps occuring:

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
```

However, this code works:

```
countries <- readOGR("countries.geojson")
```

Can someone figure out why?

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the path to the shapefile? If you unzipped to create the directory `AFG_rds` in `Downloads`, this should work: `readOGR("~/Downloads/AFG_rds/AFG_roads.shp")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Mojave and this works fine:

```
httr::GET(
  url = "http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/rds/AFG_rds.zip",
  httr::write_disk("AFG_rds.zip"),
  httr::progress()
) -> res

fils <- unzip("AFG_rds.zip", exdir = "afg-roads")

fils
## [1] "afg-roads/AFG_roads.dbf" "afg-roads/AFG_roads.prj" 
## [3] "afg-roads/AFG_roads.shp" "afg-roads/AFG_roads.shx"

rgdal::readOGR("afg-roads/AFG_roads.shp")
## OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
## Source: "/Users/bob/Development/afg-roads/AFG_roads.shp", layer: "AFG_roads"
## with 1409 features
## It has 5 fields
## class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
## features    : 1409 
## extent      : 60.6075, 74.67168, 29.38582, 38.48983  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
## coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
## variables   : 5
## names       :     MED_DESCRI,    RTT_DESCRI, F_CODE_DES, ISO,  ISOCOUNTRY 
## min values  :        Unknown, Primary Route,       Road, AFG, AFGHANISTAN 
## max values  : Without Median,       Unknown,      Trail, AFG, AFGHANISTAN
```

Comment: Works for me too. Not sure why the file name in the question is `afg.shp`; this is not the file name in the download.

Comment: I figured the OP might have renamed everything for some reason. `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem too. Don't try renaming the file. After unzipping, you will get a number of files, one of which will be a shapefile. In my case, all those files had the same name but different extensions. Then just do what you were already doing:

```
afg <- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "AFG_roads")
```

Hopefully this will work.